# Configuring RRAS and network settings on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, domain-name-system, rras

I have a brand new Windows server 2008 R2, which I want to configure for one of our branch offices connected by a permanent VPN link.

I have configured RRAS before but this time I am having a few problems. The Server should have a public ip on one network card and use nat to route traffic to the other network card which the clients all connect to.

I have established a vpn connection between this server and our head office one, but when I ping it I am getting the wrong ip address, either the public ip address, or one it is given by the vpn connection when it should be the ip address of the private network card.

Any one have any ideas where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It may just be that you have "A" records in DNS for addresses that you don't want that machine's name to resolve with. If you're doing static DNS then take out the unneeded "A" records.

If you're using dynamic DNS, though, you're going to have to do more work. RRAS and dynamic DNS has always been a little bit problematic. I suspect that your machine is registering all of its IP addresses in DNS and you're seeing round robin "load balancing" between them.

If the RRAS server is a domain controller (DC) then you're really in for a treat, because multi-homed DC's bring with them a whole host of problems.

Rather than go through all the possible scenarios here I'm going to pawn you off on Microsoft and an MVP's blog.

- http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2009/08/17/multihomed-dcs-with-dns-rras-and-or-pppoe-adapters.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2386184/en-us